# which versions of ubuntu support windows dynamic disks?

Tags: ubuntu

I was trying to install ubuntu on my system and was unable to find the newly unallocated space I had created in windows when I booted from Linux mint 19 live USB. I am not sure when or why I had converted basic to dynamic disk but now I don't want to format all my data for converting disk back to basic.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Windows dynamic disks are not compatible and do not support Linux partitions.

Also refer to this manual:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dynamic_disks